# Firebase one to one chat Json Object

Tags: json, firebase, angularfire

I am bit confused to create one to one firbase chat application JSON object.

My requirement is i need to show the chat list for each users(History of user chats). Once the user clicks one the history list user want to show the one to one chat window with selected user.

```
For Example :
User1 Chat List
 -------
| User2 |
| User5 |
| User8 |
 -------

If User1 select User5.The User1 want to show chat history with User5.
```

I need to design the object for this requirement.Any one please suggest

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-angular/f22J0moqCcU

Comment: This question is super vague; are you asking how the data nodes should be structured in Firebase to accommodate this functionality? Are you asking for code examples? What have you tried so far? What structure do you have now? What you say 'object' are we talking an ObjC objects or something else? Post some code and we'll take a look!